# How to override file in ansible using template?

Tags: ansible

I have a template in the folder path `~/sample_ansible/roles/carbon/templates/carbon.xml.j2` and I have a file named carbon.xml in the folder path `~/ansible_istio/wso2_apim/wso2am-3.0.0/repository/conf/`. I need to override `carbon.xml` file with the template. How to do this task?

My code

```
- name: Overwrite file
  copy:
    src: "~/sample_ansible/roles/carbon/templates/carbon.xml.j2"
    dest: ~/ansible_istio/wso2_apim/wso2am-3.0.0/repository/conf/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
- name: Overwrite file
  template:
    src: "~/sample_ansible/roles/carbon/templates/carbon.xml.j2"
    dest: ~/ansible_istio/wso2_apim/wso2am-3.0.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml
```

Tested:

```
# cat /tmp/carbon.xml
this is
the initial
contents

# cat /tmp/carbon.xml.j2
This is a new file with {{ansible_hostname}}

Playbook:
- name: Overwrite file
  template:
     src: /tmp/carbon.xml.j2
     dest: /tmp/carbon.xml
```

> changed: [localhost] => {
>       "changed": true,
>       "checksum": "197ece93c57d1a8eaccc6cd9928ede641eef65",
>       "dest": "/tmp/carbon.xml",
>       "diff": [],
>       "gid": 0,
>       "group": "root", ...............

```
# cat /tmp/carbon.xml
This is a new file with lxxxxx12345
```

Comment: No the file is not replacing

Comment: updated with template instead of copy, can you try now